# Cloudant auto increment field on replication

Tags: couchdb, replication, auto-increment, cloudant

Is it possible to auto increment a field of a document when performing a replication?

I have an application where a user can place markers on a map and I need to number these markers sequentially so that they can be referenced in a report. Users place these markers using a mobile client so assigning the numbers client side will cause conflicts when the database is replicated.

Is it possible to assign sequential numbers during the replication process in order to prevent conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to modify the document on replication, only to move it from the `source` to the `target` database. As you rightly say, if the source and target database contain the same document id, a conflicted document will be generated, which your application can clean up, if required.

Cloudant avoids conflicts in newly created documents by giving documents a long, non-sequential id at creation time. This avoids having nodes within a cluster communicating with each other to establish uniqueness or to coordinate sequential numbering.

You are permitted to generate your own ids but as you point out, it is difficult to guarantee uniqueness in auto-generated ids across a distributed system.

You could generate and id based on a combination of

- something unique about each mobile client
- a local sequence number

e.g. `{ "_id": "userid456:1234567"}`

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using update handlers to increment a counter on a document each time the handler is called.

`"updates": {
    "counter": "function(doc, req) { 
       if(!doc.counter) {
         doc.counter = 0;
       } 
       doc.counter += 1;
       return [doc, JSON.stringify(doc.counter)];
    }"
 }`

Before replication I check whether documents requiring the auto incremented id has already been assigned a value. If not, I call the update handler and assign the returned value. When all documents have received a value I continue with replication.